# iOS UIStackView individually changing the spacing of UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, spacing, uistackview

Looking through the documentation for UIStackView's I found that changing the UIStackView's 'spacing' property to 30 would simultaneously change the distance between all of it's arranged subviews.

However I couldn't find a property or method to change the distance between individual subviews, I tried to use UILayoutGuide but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add spacer views in between your content views if you want to control the spacing individually.

Comment: Is it not possible to create a NSLayoutConstraint between the current arranged subview and the one before it?

Comment: Actually I haven't tried that. You should try it and report back. :^)

Comment: If you are targeting **iOS 11 or newer** you can now use `setCustomSpacing`.